# Retrieving error data from a web service application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, response

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to retrieve error data from a web service application after making to that an HTTP POST request. I would like to receive that data including the `errors` root.

In a service app controller I have

```
format.json {
  render :json => @account.errors, :status => 202
}
```

The return data returned, for example, is

```
{\"base\":\"Invalid submitting\",\"name\":\"To short\"}
```

I would like to receive back data like this

```
# Note 'errors'
"{\"errors\":{\"base\":\"Invalid submitting\",\"name\":\"To short\"}"}
```

**How can I make that?**

---

A solution is to make this

```
render :json => '{"errors":' + @account.errors.to_json + '}'
```

but I don't think it is the right\correct way. RoR certainly has some features to do that better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to construct an equivalent hash and then use that:

```
error_hash = { 'errors' => @account.errors.to_h }

render(:json => error_hash, :status => 302)
```

Comment: Using your code I get this error 'StandardError in Users/accountsController#new

Invalid JSON string'. The correct version is 'error_hash = { 'errors' => @account.errors.to_hash }'